# Program gets hung up when I use "delete" function

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a program where it'll take in info from a user, and the user will have options on what to do. The options are to add, modify, delete, display certain info, find the average, and exit.
I have written code for all of them but I can't get my delete function to work.
Here is my code:

```
void delete_student(struct students *list, int *count)                  //Delete's Selected student
{
    int id4;
    int k;
    if (*count != 0)
    {
    printf("\nEnter the ID of the student you wish to delete: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &id4);
    for (int i = 0; i < *count; i++)                //Searches for the selected student
    {
        k = i;
        if (list[i].id == id4)
        {
            printf("\nStudent found.\nDeleting...\n");
            for (int c = k; c < *count; c++)            //Deletes the student if found
            {
                list[c].id = list[c + 1].id;
                strcpy(list[c].name, list[c + 1].name);
                list[c].age = list[c + 1].age;
                strcpy(list[c].dept, list[c + 1].dept);
                list[c].grade = list[c + 1].grade;
            }
            *count = *count - 1;
            printf("\nDeletion Complete.\n");
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("\nStudent not found. Please try again.\n");
        break;
    }
}
else
    printf("\nNo student's to delete.\n");
}
```

Edit:
When I go through the program, and I select to use this function, it'll ask me for the "ID" and then it does nothing and has a blinking cursor.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
There's more code if you need it.

Is this how the last element would be deleted:

```
list[*count].id = 0;
strcpy(list[*count].name, NULL);
list[*count].age = 0;
strcpy(list[*count].dept, NULL);
list[*count].grade = 0;
```

Comment: Please clarify why this is not working. Are you getting a compiler error? A segmentation fault at runtime? Does the code run, but not behave as it should?

Comment: @ZachStark When I go through the program, and I select to use this function, it'll ask me for the "ID" and then it does nothing and has a blinking cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scanf()` statement has an incorrect format string. You don't need to add the trailing newline; scanf takes care of it. Change that line to `scanf("%d", &id4);` (no newline) and it should work.
 
I just wrote a small stub program that compares scanf with and without the newline, and it replicates your error.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Look at the other answers, though; there are still some other problems in your code. I just happened to find the right one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `break` statement at the end of your `for` loop that probably shouldn't be there.  Just delete that one.

```
else
        printf("\nStudent not found. Please try again.\n");
    break;
}     ^
      |
      +------ this one
```

That `printf` is a bit inaccurate too; it will get printed out on every iteration of the loop where you didn't happen to find a matching ID.

Comment: Ahhh thank you for pointing that out. Where would you suggest I put it?

Comment: +1 Good catch. But that should not cause the program to hang. Also, the OP should properly handle if deleting the last element in the struct.

Comment: @Mahesh If I'm deleting the last element, would I just change all the values to NULL or 0?

Comment: @PM Yes, if the user input is to delete last student. Because you have no more elements to iterate. So, you should be careful about not iterating the elements past array size.

Comment: @Mahesh I added the code for the way I thought the last element should be deleted, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
for (int c = k; c < *count; c++)
```

should probably instead be:

```
for (int c = k; c < *count - 1; c++)
```

As written, it reads one past the end of the valid array.  The results are undefined.  And in particular, the `strcpy` calls may go quite badly.  When it gets to the last entry in that loop, `list[c+1]` refers to an entry that does not exist (based on *count).

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf` hangs as it never gets to read your number. No `\n` needed. Use `%d` only.